# mysql return one row of right table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a huge problem with MYSQL.

I have a table called tperson with the following content

```
+--------------+------------+  
| tperson_id   | first_name |  
+--------------+------------+  
| 1            | juan       |  
| 2            | miguel     |  
| 3            | Carlos     |  
| 4            | Diego      |  
+--------------+------------+
```

on the second table i have this data

```
+--------------+------------+------------+  
| tperson_id   | trans_code | date_added |  
+--------------+------------+------------+
| 1            | 2000-01    |2020/03/03  |  
| 1            | 2000-02    |2020/03/04  |  
| 2            | 1999-05    |2019/12/25  |  
| 3            | 1999-06    |2019/12/26  |  
| 3            | 1999-07    |2019/12/27  |  
+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Now I want to have this result in mysql

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+  
| tperson_id   | first_name | trans_code | date_added |  
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+  
| 1            | juan       |2000-02     | 2020/03/04 |  
| 2            | miguel     |1999-05     | 2019/12/25 |  
| 3            | Carlos     |1999-07     | 2019/12/27 |  
| 4            | Diego      | null       | null       |  
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

what is the right MYsql statement to generation the result I want?

pls anyone help, I keep looking for the answer found nowhere. I am not good in any database.

thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your 2nd table name is `tdate`, and data on `trans_code` and `date_added` that's being selected is the latest value if there are more than one data from the same `tperson_id` on table `tdate`

```
SELECT tp.tperson_id, tp.first_name, MAX(td.trans_code), MAX(td.date_added) 
  FROM tperson tp
  LEFT JOIN tdate td 
    ON tp.tperson_id = td.tperson_id 
 GROUP BY tp.tperson_id
```

Comment: Thank yo so much Vincent Jonathan, from the bottom of my heart. You are helping me sleep. God bless

Comment: @abigailpattugalan I guess it's just lucky that the max transcode always equals the max date added